# Debian Wheezy : how to set noatime parameter for root FS?

Tags: linux, filesystems, embedded, debian

I have an embedded ARM system that uses Debian Wheezy.  I want to mount the SD root fs with the "noatime" option.  I would normally just add this to /etc/fstab, however on my system the /etc/fstab is empty, the root fs is definitely mounted by the kernel however.

Does anyone know where to set the noatime option in a case like this?  The mounting of the RFS is happening somewhere in Debian, as I see this message on startup.

[   14.442749] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)

Comment: Do you have a compressed initial file system which mounts the real one?  Do you have a bootloader such us uboot or grub which passes a kernel command line?

Answer (score 2):

You could remount it with the noatime option after the system has already booted.

in my case to remount the root filesystem with noatime:

`sudo mount -o remount -o noatime /`

you can see the current options with the command **mount** and checking the line that say **on /**

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/3984fee6-c70a-4fee-96a0-6d4a4103abc6 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
```